# Authorization on Rest Api

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am calling a web API from another site and the API is in another site. Want to authorize user but i cant see user identity on the API that i call. How can i handle this ? What is the best practice for this ?

```
public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userName = actionContext.RequestContext.Principial.Identity.Name;
        }
```

But the name is empty. I also tried HttpContext.Current.User but it is also null. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with

1- I changed the api's Anonymous Auth to false and windows auth to true.

2- I added global asax file this line ;

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

I can see now  the domain name ..